# Server-Sent Events using Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler

Tags: javascript, c++, html, poco, server-sent-events

I'm trying to "stream" data to an HTML5 page using server-sent events.

This tutorial http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ was quite helpful to get the client side working.

But for the server side, I'm doing something similar to the HTTPServer example in http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf

The html5rocks.com tutorial gave me the following idea for the request handler's code:

```c
void MyRequestHandler::handleRequest (HTTPServerRequest &req, HTTPServerResponse &resp)
{
    resp.setStatus(HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK);

    resp.add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    resp.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    ostream& out = resp.send();

    while (out.good())
    {
        out << "data: " << "some data" << "\n\n";
        out.flush();

        Poco::Thread::sleep(500)
    }
}
```

and the HTML5 page's source:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>HTLM5Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo">hello</p>
        <script>
            var msgCounter = 0;
            var source;
            var data;
            if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined")
            {
                source = new EventSource('/stream');
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Event source created";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Are you using IE ?";
            }

            source.addEventListener('message', function(e)
            {
                msgCounter++;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Message received (" + msgCounter + ") !<br/>"+ e.data;
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The good thing is that, when opening the html page, the data gets streamed and I get a correct outpout (the text between the  tag gets updated as expected.

The problem is that when I close the page in the browser, the POCO program crashes, and I get the following message in the console:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 22.234 s
Press any key to continue.
```

(I'm using Code::Blocks, that's why the return value and the execution time are displayed)

Event when I put the while() loop between try{ }catch(...){} the program still crashes without entering the catch (same thing happens when I put the entire main()'s content in between try/catch )

The main program contains only these instructions:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyServerApp myServer;
    myServer.run(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know what could cause that crash and how I can fix it, please.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Hey, did you end up finding a solution to this problem? I'm in the same exact situation and was considering using a reactor on a server socket to handle closing a connection manually.

Comment: At the time, I was developing on a Windows7 OS. If I remember correctly, that's why the try/catch didn't work. So ended up not using server-sent events on that platform. However, I think the same code (i.e. w/ exception handling) should be fine on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm also developing a server on Windows 7 right now. After digging into the documentation, I was able to deal with the exception by registering my own error handler that ignores the one thrown when a client disconnects.

Comment: Cool. Could you please share your code? I think it would be beneficial for other people who are dealing with similar problems.

Comment: Absolutely! I'll post an answer with my code when I get home.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I was able to deal with this issue by registering my own error handler that simply ignores the exception thrown when an SSE-client disconnects:

```
#include <Poco\ErrorHandler.h>

// Other includes, using namespace..., etc.

class ServerErrorHandler : public ErrorHandler
{
public:
    void exception(const Exception& e)
    {
        // Ignore an exception that's thrown when an SSE connection is closed. 
        //
        // Info: When the server is handling an SSE request, it keeps a persistent connection through a forever loop.
        //       In order to handle when a client disconnects, the request handler must detect such an event. Alas, this
        //       is not possible with the current request handler in Poco (we only have 2 params: request and response).
        //       The only hack for now is to simply ignore the exception generated when the client disconnects :(
        //
        if (string(e.className()).find("ConnectionAbortedException") == string::npos)
            poco_debugger_msg(e.what());
    }
};

class ServerApp : public ServerApplication 
{
protected:
    int main(const vector<string>& args) 
    {
        // Create and register our error handler
        ServerErrorHandler error_handler;
        ErrorHandler::set(&error_handler);

        // Normal server code, for example:
        HTTPServer server(new RequestHandlerFactory, 80, new HTTPServerParams);
        server.start();

        waitForTerminationRequest();
        server.stop();

        return Application::EXIT_OK;
    }
};


POCO_SERVER_MAIN(ServerApp);
```

However, I must say that this is an ugly hack. Moreover, the error handler is global to the application which makes it even less desirable as a solution. The correct way would be detect the disconnection and handle it. For that Poco must pass the `SocketStream` to the request handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to catch Poco Exceptions:

```
try {
    MyServerApp myServer;
    return myServer.run(argc, argv);        
}catch(const Poco::Exception& ex) {
    std::cout << ex.displayText() << std::endl;
    return Poco::Util::Application::EXIT_SOFTWARE;
}
```